# Создание простой разметки страницы

Tags: html, css, css3, вёрстка, адаптивная-верстка

Никак не врублюсь во флексбокс. Есть вот такая разметка:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Flexbox layout</title>
        <style>
            body {
                display: flex;
            }

            footer aside.contacts a img {
                width: 30px;
                height: 30px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <header>
            <img src="https://fakeimg.pl/2000x100/?text=First+banner" />
            <img src="https://fakeimg.pl/2000x100/?text=Second+banner" />
        </header>
        <nav>
            <div class="breadcrumbs">
                <a href="/">Main</a>
                &nbsp;/&nbsp;
                <a href="/inner">Inner</a>
            </div>
            <form class="search-form">
                <input type="search" name="query" />
                <button type="submit">Search</button>
            </form>
            <h1 class="page-header">Flexbox layout</h1>
        </nav>
        <main>
            <article>
                <p>
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor 
                    incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud 
                    exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure 
                    dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. 
                    Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
                </p>
                <p>
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor 
                    incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud 
                    exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure 
                    dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. 
                    Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
                </p>
                <p>
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor 
                    incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud 
                    exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure 
                    dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. 
                    Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
                </p>
                <p>
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor 
                    incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud 
                    exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure 
                    dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. 
                    Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
                </p>
            </article>
            <aside class="icons">
                <img src="https://fakeimg.pl/100x100/?text=First+icon" />
                <img src="https://fakeimg.pl/100x100/?text=Second+icon" />
            </aside>
        </main>
        <footer>
            <section class="banners">
                <img src="https://fakeimg.pl/2000x100/?text=First+banner" />
                <img src="https://fakeimg.pl/2000x100/?text=Second+banner" />
            </section>
            <aside class="copyrights">
                &copy; My, 2020
            </aside>
            <aside class="contacts">
                <a href="https://vk.com" target="_blank"><img src="https://vk.com/favicon.ico"/></a>
                <a href="https://www.instagram.com" target="_blank"><img src="https://www.instagram.com/favicon.ico"/></a>
            </aside>
        </footer>
    </body>
</html>
```

Мне надо чтобы весь контент страницы (вместе с хедером и футером) был ужат процентов до 80 примерно. Ну вот как на stackoverflow, например. То есть отступы большие слева и справа. Сверху хедер, под ним nav, под ним article, а вложенный в main aside справа от article (процентов на 20 от main в ширину). В футере сначала на весь футер section, а потом слева копирайты, справа контакты.

Помогите пожалуйста!

Comment: Вы скиньте `css` который у Вас уже получился, а люди попытаются его отредактировать. с Уважением

Comment: @Август он есть в верстке. Честно говоря это все что я понял из flexbox(( Очень сложная тема...

Comment: я Вас понял. но для этой цели Вам не обязательно использовать `flex`, достаточно задать margin-ы по бокам. или Вам всё таки через `flex`              дать ответ с результатом?

Comment: @Август через flex было бы более современно и адаптивно. Тем более что там не только отступы нужны, но и прочие описанные детали (в main и футере).

Comment: @ПЭХАПЕШНИК, вот так https://codepen.io/august_august/pen/zYGPjWP ?

Comment: @Август спасибо большое!

Comment: @ПЭХАПЕШНИК, я успел увидеть, что Вы там еще **что-то** хотели доделать. пишите, не стесняйтесь

Comment: @Август не, мне показалось что футер не прижался к низу, но вроде все норм.

Comment: @ПЭХАПЕШНИК, то есть Вам нужно, чтобы футер прям прилип к самому низу экрана?

Comment: @Август Ну во всяком случае если экран будет больше чем контент страницы то он не должен вверх уезжать. И еще чтобы контент копирайтов и контактов в футере был вертикально по центру (сейчас когда я пытаюсь задать высоту футера контент прижимается к верху)